# Alternate way to using cursor/loop in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, sp-send-dbmail

I want to see if there is any way to do what I'm trying to do without using cursors, or any looping logic. I have these 2 tables. There is a ONE-MANY relationship between `FileRunData` and `Invoice`, and they're linked by `RunId/FileRunId`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileRunData](
    [RunId] [uniqueidentifier] primary key,
    [Status] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [IsEmailSent] [bit] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice](
    [FileRunId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [InvoiceId] [uniqueidentifier] primary key,
    [InvoiceType] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](25) NULL
)
```

I want to send an email notification for the following condition.

In the `FileRunData` if `Status='Processed' and IsEmailSent=0`, then I have to check all the rows in the `Invoice` table for that `FileRunId`, and if their `Status is 'Invoiced'`, then I have to send an email.

My approach (will be using cursor here)

1. select RunIds from FileRunData
2. for each RunId, get the number of rows for that RunId from Invoice
3. get the number of rows for that RunId which have Status='Invoiced'
4. If both 3&4 are equal, then send the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by adding a couple of negations in, the problem is simpler to understand, unless I've severely misunderstood you. We *don't* want to send an email if there's any row in `Invoice` which has a status *other* than `Invoiced`:

```
SELECT frd.RunId
FROM FileRunData frd
WHERE frd.Status = 'Processed' AND
      frd.IsEmailSent = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (select * from Invoice i
                   where i.FileRunID = frd.RunID and
                         i.Status != 'Invoiced')
```

should select the IDs for runs which meet your conditions. Unfortunately, if you need to use these `RunId` values and send one email for each such result, then unfortunately, at this point you'll still have to use a cursor<sup>1</sup> to process this result set and make the actual `sp_send_dbmail` calls.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or any morally equivalent way of processing each row in turn. I'd normally just use a cursor but some people have an aversion to the word even appearing in their SQL and insist on creating temp tables and while loops instead, for example.

Comment: Yup, this looks like it will work! Yeah, we don't want to send an email if there's even a single row in Invoice for that RunId with a Status other than Invoiced.. thanks!

Comment: One thing- what if I want to use each RunID in each email that I'm sending? It wouldn't make sense to send the emails without including this RunID. also, is that possible w/o cursors?

Comment: The reason I'm asking for alternate ways is because I'd seen many SO posts recommending Against it!

Comment: I'd say avoid cursors whilst you're creating a result set (like the above) that can be expressed in a set-based manner. But once you're needing to call a stored procedure once for each row *of that set* (such as `sp_send_dbmail`) then you're forced to use a cursor or something like it. It's the correct thing to do, [*in those circumstances*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606709/iterate-through-rows-in-sql-server-2008)